Alexa Skill - Testing Permissions
I have a skill that requests users email addresses so alexa::profile:email:read permission needs to be enabled when a particular intent is triggered.
I have this setup but I am unsure how to configure the Alexa Simulator to have this permission enabled so i can test my code for when it is enabled.
